# IIS module and WCF

Tags: wcf, authentication, module, httpmodule, httpcontext

I have written an IIS module (base IHttpModule) that does some custom (OpenAuth) authentication before preceding to my WCF REST service.
I have extended GenericPrincipal to track my user, with an IIdentity, and set 
the context.User field to my new principal:
`application.context.User = principal`

However, when I receive the context in WCF (next step down the pipeline), the User shows up as a "default" unauthenticated WindowsPrincipal (not the GenericPrincipal that i set).

I see lots of stuff on the net about making this work (including aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" for serviceHostingEnvironment, playing with OperationContext, etc...) But nothing I have tried seems to work.

Two questions:

1. Is there a way to get this to work (or am I just barking up the wrong tree here).
2. What would be the canonical way to do this, or maybe the more "WCF" way to handle this custom authentication.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set your principal identity during the authorization phase in WCF. This requires a custom Authorization Policy. I suggest you read [this article](http://www.leastprivilege.com/CustomPrincipalsAndWCF.aspx) for more info. I've not tried to do this with a custom HttpModule and REST, but I have successfully done so with the default authentication schemes.